# Strange Error in External CSS Execution

Tags: html, css, web, xhtml

I was told by my teacher to submit an External Style Sheet assignment. I created one successfully but for some reason when ever I try to Execute the Style sheet with my Webpage the First Line of Style doesn't get executed (in this case the h1 tag)

I am using Dreamweaver CC

I requested my teacher to see if i am doing something wrong and even she couldn't find a solution to it.

Here is the CSS Code

```
  @charset "utf-8";
<style type="text/css">
h1 {font:calibri; color:#0C0; border-bottom-style:solid; border-bottom-color:#363;}
h4 {border-bottom-style:solid; border-bottom-color:#363}
p.normal{font-size:16px; background-color:#99C; text-decoration:underline}
p.warning{font-size:24px; background-color:#CCC; color:#F00; text-decoration:line-through}
.major{ font-size:18px; font-variant:small-caps; font-weight:900}
.indent{text-indent:40px}
.align{text-align:center}
.name {font:calibri; background-color:#000; color:#CCC; font-size:20px; font-style:italic; font-weight:bolder}
</style>
```

and this is the HTML code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>External CSS</title>
<style type="text/css">
@import url("External CSS (Waheed).css");
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1 class="align">Heading</h1>
<h4>Subheading</h4>
<p class="normal">Test </p>
<p class="warning">Test 2</p>
<p class="major">Test 3</p>
<p class="indent">Test 4</p>
<p class="align">Test 5</p>
<p class="name"> By: Mohammad Saad Waheed (201211034)</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: You don't use style tags in external stylesheets. Style tags are HTML.

Comment: To clarify @sevenseacat's comment, the tags `<style type="text/css">` and `</style>` do not belong in your CSS file.